# Getting URL of images in Google Images with Google Custom Search API?

Tags: json, image, rest, search, google-custom-search

I am trying to use Google Custom Search API to get URL of images in Google Images. How do I set up my custom search site to use images.google.com as its site to search? I just tried to use the Google Images url (images.google.com) when I sat up my Custom Search, but that does not seem to work.

When I try to do a REST call this is what I get:

```
{
"title": "Google Custom Search - tomat",
"totalResults": "0",
"searchTerms": "tomat",
"count": 10,
"inputEncoding": "utf8",
"outputEncoding": "utf8",
"safe": "off",
"cx": "THIS IS WHERE THE CX NUMBER IS"
}
```

I am trying to get the image URL of the three first hits on a search query. Any ideas?

Comment: try adding searchType = "image" or searchType:"image" to your parameters

Comment: @RamRaider I does'nt work. I get :   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - tomat",
    "totalResults": "0",
    "searchTerms": "tomat",
    "count": 10,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "THIS IS WHERE THE CX NUMBER IS",
    "searchType": "image"
   }

Comment: No examples but got that from the google documentation. When you make your request to the api you must( I would assume ) send a bunch of parameters as part of the request. If you arefetching with cURL over GET then these parameters are appended to the url as a querystring, if you are using POST they are sent as post params as a curl option. Add the searchType parameter with a value of image to these parameters before sending or share you code that you use to make the request so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @RamRaider I edited the comment. I had a typo in the parameters and got the searchType to work, but it still returns 0 hits.

Comment: @RamRaider This is the query string: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=KEY_IS_HERE&cx=CX_NUMBER_HERE&searchType=image&q=tomat

Comment: @RamRaider I fixed it. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to have Image Search enabled in the control panel and have searchType=image in the query, but what I had to add was *.google.com to sites to search. When I used the wildcard at google.com it worked. :)